# Is there a way to schedule a python script (the script uses Google API to read google sheets) using crontab?

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, cron, jupyter-server

I am trying to schedule a python script using crontab on a web server, but the file doesn't run at all. The script uses Google API to read google sheets. Other files that don't use Google API run as expected. Why is it so?